# UIActivityIndicator spinning while UIView hierarchy being constructed?

Tags: ios, uiview, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityindicatorview

is there a way to animate an UIActivityIndicator while constructing a complex UIView hierarchy? I have a complex hierarchy, to be added via 'addSubview:' in 'viewDidLoad' (in a mostly storyboard project, but this scene is dynamically created). Not fiddling with GCD, the UI blocks as long as initialization takes. Putting the initialization into 'dispatch_sync' (shown below) does not display/animate the indicator, putting it into 'dispatch_async (dispatch_get_global_queue (0,0),...' creates a crash (because UIKit code needs to run on main queue?), and putting it into 'dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue(),...' creates a deadlock (as announces by Apple, I guess).

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    dispatch_sync (dispatch_get_global_queue (0,0), ^{
        // initialization here
        })
}
```

So what is the direction to go?

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a method and try

```
– performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
– performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:
```

Comment: Sunkehappy, I tried this as well: Put the initialization into a new method, and call this in 'viewDidLoad' using 'performSelectorOnMainThread'. Unfortunately, nothing changes: During initialization, the old screen is displayed without spinner, and after initialization, the spinner shortly flashes on screen, before the segue animation leads to the second screen.

Comment: You say the spinner flashes on the screen. Does this mean the subview is added successfully? So can you try to find out why it 'splashes', why it disappear?

Comment: Well, littering the code with breakpoints, I see that the spinner is added correctly, but it sits still during all the initalization ('performSegueWithIdentifier', 'viewDidLoad', 'viewWillAppear' are all called correctly). It only starts spinning when the final animation of the segue (flip, in my case) is done after leaving 'viewWillAppear'.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start the activity indicator in viewDidLoad, then schedule the initialization using performSelectorInBackground:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(finishInitializing) withObject:nil];
}

-(void)finishInitializing {
    // finish resource-intensive setup
    // ...

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
        // create view hierarchy
        // ...
    });
}
```

This allows `viewDidLoad` to return so the spinner can animate on the main thread.

Comment: Christopher, thanks for the answer. However, 'performSelectorInBackground:' creates a new thread, which obviously is not the main thread (= UI thread) anymore, and there, calls to UIKit crash complaining about this not being the correct thread.

Comment: Yes, my idea was that you do your resource-intensive work on that thread, then finish up your UI layout on the main thread in the `dispatch_async` call. Any slowness in your "complex UIView hierarchy" is almost certainly not in UIKit, but in whatever you're doing to prep the layout. You should never need an activity indicator just to lay out views.

Comment: What is done in the initialization is pulling objects from CoreData (representing areas on a floor plan) and constructing views accordingly. I know that there may still be issues with rendering performance in the areas (I removed the shadow that visual design wanted to make it responsive enough for dragging), but I would like to think that rendering happens only for visible areas.

Comment: You should not load Core Data objects on a background thread and hand them to the main thread. It can result in crashes that are extremely hard to reproduce. We have a similar use case where we load CD in the background, copy the necessary fields into value objects, then use those value objects in the `dispatch_async` call on the main queue for rendering. We were initially passing the CD objects to the main queue block directly, and never experienced a crash in testing, but had several crashes reported in the wild.

Comment: Maybe you ran into the same trap I did (which surfaced recently, but unrelated to this issue here): CD needs some precautions when threads are involved - never recycle one NSManagedObjectContext in different threads, and never pass NSManagedObjects between threads. It's written up in the CD programming guide under the heading "Concurrency".